# Oracle SqlPlus - saving output in a file but don't show on screen

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Using SqlPlus for Oracle, how do I save the output of a query in a file but not show it on the terminal/prompt.

Comment: SET TERMOUT OFF is not working wiht my SqlPlus. This sqlplus `-s ${ORA_CONN_STR} <<EOF >/dev/null`  i.e. answer by @AshishAnand worked for me.

Comment: "SET TERMOUT is the way to do it and it requires a script - it doesn't do anything at an interactive prompt" - https://community.oracle.com/thread/2140535?tstart=0

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Right from the SQL*Plus manual
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch8.htm#sthref1597

> SET TERMOUT
>
> SET TERMOUT OFF suppresses the display so that you can spool output **from a script** without 
>   seeing it on the screen.
>
> If both spooling to file and writing to terminal are not required, use SET TERMOUT OFF in >SQL scripts to disable terminal output.
>
> SET TERMOUT is not supported in iSQL*Plus

Comment: "SET TERMOUT is the way to do it and it requires a script - it doesn't do anything at an interactive prompt" - community.oracle.com/thread/2140535?tstart=0

Answer (score 22):

Try this:

```
SET TERMOUT OFF; 
spool M:\Documents\test;
select * from employees;
/
spool off;
```

Comment: @AlexPoole the spool command.  IMO this is a more complete answer.

Comment: [be careful using semicolon `;` and slash `/` both, as that will duplicate your query result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1079949/4023950)

Answer (score 11):

Try This:

```
sqlplus -s ${ORA_CONN_STR} <<EOF >/dev/null
```

Comment: On UNIX it just hangs on a prompt prefixed by ">"

Comment: `source .env; ORA_CONN="${USER}/${PASS}@{DB}"; sqlplus -s <<EOF>/dev/null $ORA_CONN select 1 from dual; EOF` worked for me

Answer (score 3):

`set termout off` doesn't work from the command line, so create a file e.g. `termout_off.sql` containing the line:

```
set termout off
```

and call this from the SQL prompt:

```
SQL> @termout_off
```