# what does the "2"mean in SQL*Plus?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g, sqlplus

I am new to Oracle.
And I have come across a problem.

Firstly,I want to check the privileges of the sysman account:

```
SQL>  select * from dba_sys_privs where grantee='sysman';

no rows selected
```

I know that it means there is no content in my view dba_sys_privs.  But anyway,I have aready built a database.  So, I try again, just shortening the statement:

```
SQL>  select * from dba_sys_privs
  2
```

So here are my two questions:

1. what happened to my database? I have already set up a database
2. what does the "2" mean?  Does it mean the next row or something else?

Answer (score 31):

You have entered a new line character (pressed `return`) without entering a statement termination i.e. `;`.  Compare your second statement with the first one you posted.  So yes, the `2` means the client is awaiting further input.

To run the second statement, simply enter a slash `/`

---

As for why your first statement returned no rows, in Oracle database object names (including users) are in *upper-case*.

```
select * from dba_sys_privs where grantee='SYSMAN';
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21145229/1509264) in the question "When do I need to use a semicolon vs a slash in Oracle SQL?"

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar situaion due to my inserts did not work as expected. I used a insert statement followed by "commit;", it just says committed, but when I use sql developer to view the record, I could not find it. So I tried to run select from sqlplus and got a number.
Later DBA told me to skip the "commit", then I could see the exception thrown.