# oracle SQL plus how to end command in SQL file?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have SQL file with few commands.

What it the correct way to end lines in the script?

Is it slash [/] semicolon [;] both?

Is there any diffarent between regular sqls and Stored procedure code?

Thank you

Comment: Here is a thread with similar intent and good explanations:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079949/sql-the-semicolon-or-the-slash

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For normal SQL statements, either a `/` on a line by itself, or a `;` at the end of the command, will work fine.

For statements that include PL/SQL code, such as `CREATE FUNCTION`, `CREATE PROCEDURE`, `CREATE PACKAGE`, `CREATE TYPE`, or anonymous blocks (`DECLARE`/`BEGIN`/`END`), a `;` will not execute the command.  Since PL/SQL uses semicolons as line terminators, its use as a command terminator must be suppressed in these statements.  So in these cases, you must use `/` to execute the command.

In my experience, people prefer to use the semicolon when possible and use the slash only when required.

Note that for SQLPlus client commands -- such as `SET` or `EXECUTE` -- no command terminator is necessary at all, although people often end them with a semicolon out of habit.

Comment: +1, good answer. I think people prefer to use the semicolon when possible is it's more natural to end the command with a semicolon and hit return, rather than hit return, type a slash, and hit return again. The slash must be the only character on the line when used to execute the command buffer.

Answer (score 2):

; is the way you should end your sql commands, same goes for PLSQL procedures:

`select * from dual;`

`select sysdate from dual;`

`select table_name from user tables;`

`exec dbms_output.putline('Hello');`

Answer (score 1):

Usually we can use "`;`" to end sql statement,
 
but for create `functions`, `triggers`, `procedures`  you have to use "`/`" after "`;`" to end SQL statement.
 
"`/`" might not be required when you use some developers tool like, oracle SQL developer, toad etc, but it should be mandate when you execute your query directly in the linux machine.