# Grant permission to stored procedure in sql script

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

I have a `.sql` file with create procedure statements followed by a grant statement as shown below.

```
    create or replace
    PROCEDURE PROCEDURE_NAME()
    AS 
      BEGIN
      .....................
      END;

GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE_NAME TO ROLE_NAME;
```

If I remove the grant statement everything works fine. However with grant statement it gives the following error.

```
Error(23,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "GRANT"
```

What am I missing here ? Can grant statement be not included in script as it does when we use it with `create` statements ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a slash, I presume, behind the END;

```
create or replace
    PROCEDURE PROCEDURE_NAME()
    AS 
      BEGIN
      .....................
      END;
/                --> this

GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE_NAME TO ROLE_NAME;
```

Answer (score 1):

In sqlplus, for normal sql statements like `select`, `insert`, `delete` DDLs (`ALTER,CREATE TABLE` etc, either a `/` , or a `;` at the end of the query, works fine.

However, for PL/SQL codes such as those which include `CREATE FUNCTION`, `CREATE PROCEDURE`, `CREATE PACKAGE`, `CREATE TYPE`, or anonymous blocks (`DECLARE/BEGIN/END`), a semicolon at the end is not sufficient. We need a `/` to execute the command.

So, Include a `/` after `END;`  and it should work fine.

[oracle SQL plus how to end command in SQL file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406835/oracle-sql-plus-how-to-end-command-in-sql-file)