# Function - oracle (PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "")

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a simple oracle function which loops over some records and then inserts records for each of those ..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION addNewRolesToAllGDP
    return NUMBER
    is dummy number;
BEGIN
    FOR applicationId IN (SELECT APPID
                          FROM GRPAPPLICATIONINSTANCES
                          where GRPAPPID = (select GRPAPPID
                                            from GRPAPPLICATIONS
                                            where GRPNAME = 'DIGITAL_OFFICE')
                            AND APPID in (select APPID from APPLICATIONS where REGEXP_LIKE(APPNAME, '[[:digit:]]')))
        LOOP
            INSERT INTO ROLES (ROLID, ROLNAME, APPID)
            VALUES (SEQROLES.nextval,
                    'INVENTORY_REQUESTER',
                    applicationId);
            INSERT INTO ROLES (ROLID, ROLNAME, APPID)
            VALUES (SEQROLES.nextval,
                    'INVENTORY_OWNER',
                    applicationId);
            INSERT INTO ROLES (ROLID, ROLNAME, APPID)
            VALUES (SEQROLES.nextval,
                    'INVENTORY_ADMIN',
                    applicationId);
        END LOOP;
    RETURN 1;
END;

alter function addNewRolesToAllGDP compile;
```

This statements gives me the following in USER_ERRORS:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following: ( return compress compiled wrapped

Comment: In the `INSERT` statements, you should use `applicationId.APPID` instead of `applicationId`

Comment: @Aleksej That's one thing that was wrong probably. Still get the same error though.

Comment: what line does it report the error for?

Comment: @DaveCosta sequence 1, line 1, position 29

Comment: Compiles in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f3ad05aa24cbd9378855be7f34d09d56).

Comment: @PonderStibbons still getting 'ORA-06575: Package or function ADDNEWROLESTOALLGDP is in an invalid state' when trying to run with: 'select addNewRolesToAllGDP() from DUAL;' and the line is still there in USER_ERRORS

Comment: Have you tried to call the function without `()`? Like this: `SELECT addNewRolesToAllGDP FROM DUAL;`

Comment: @Paplusc Still get the invalid state message without

Comment: You can try to compile it as standalone function, maybe error is thrown because it is part of package and previous lines causes error.

Comment: @PonderStibbons if that's the case, then why is the error line named after my error? There are no other errors as far as I see.

Comment: For example, when the closing semicolon in the previous line is missing, Oracle shows an error in the next. I don't know if this is the case here, but your function compiles for me, as you see in dbfiddle, so I guess that error is somewhere else.

Comment: I used same @PonderStibbons dbfiddle in my oracle db and works like a charm

Comment: The weird behaviour made me switch tools. Was working in Intellij, which gave me this errors. Now switch to sqlDeveloper and there it compiles and executes.. Lol.. Still got another error though, but I will make another post for that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used to run this in Intellij which gave me the stated behaviour. After running it from sqlDeveloper it compiled fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but I notice that you do not have a slash following the END statement of the function.  In Oracle tools, without that slash, the statement does not actually get terminated, and the ALTER command is included as part of the same statement.  This can cause weird syntax errors.

If this is the problem, fundamentally this question is a duplicate of [oracle SQL plus how to end command in SQL file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406835/oracle-sql-plus-how-to-end-command-in-sql-file).

**Edited to add** As others have said in comments, the same code seems to compile fine for me when I cut-and-paste it from your post. Based on the error and the position where it is reported, my best guess is that at the end of the first line your original source has some invisible character that is causing the parser error.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error message for a missing comma in the procedure definition and got compiled after adding the comma.

Procedure definition before fix

```
PROCEDURE CREATE_WO(p_wo_type  IN NUMBER,
                          p_id     IN NUMBER,
                          p_do_commit        IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'Y'
                          p_return_value     OUT VARCHAR2)
                          IS
    BEGIN   
      ...
   END;
```

Error Message

```
Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 8, column 9:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:

   ) , * & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem =>
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
   like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset
```

Procedure definition after fix, note the comma at the end of p_do_commit

```
PROCEDURE CREATE_WO(p_wo_type  IN NUMBER,
                          p_id     IN NUMBER,
                          p_do_commit        IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'Y',
                          p_return_value     OUT VARCHAR2)
                          IS
    BEGIN   
      ...
   END;
```