# SQL*PLUS Trigger has not compiled but no errors shown up

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus, database-trigger

I am trying to create sequence and trigger by using `sqlplus` and everything is written in term of bash script.
My code is as following

```
su -p oracle -c "$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -l mydb/mypass@localhost:1521/xe << !
    create sequence SEQ_NAME start with 1000 maxvalue 9999;

    create or replace trigger TRG_NAME
    before insert on TABLE_NAME
    for each row
    begin
        select SEQ_NAME.nextval into :new.MY_ID from dual;
    end;
!
"
```

After executing the above command, I expected to receive some logs look like

```
Sequence created

Trigger compiled
```

But only the log `Sequence created` appears. As a result, only the sequence is created and trigger is not created. I know that by checking on **SQL Developer** tool

The thing is when I use **SQL Developer** tool and execute the script

```
create sequence SEQ_NAME start with 1000 maxvalue 9999;

create or replace trigger TRG_NAME
before insert on TABLE_NAME
for each row
begin
select SEQ_NAME.nextval into :new.MY_ID from dual;
end;
```

Then everything works fine! Sequence and Trigger are created!

Any idea for this problem?

Comment: Try to put `/` after both command ends

Comment: Unrelated, but: the `su` seems useless, why can't you run `sqlplus` directly?

Comment: More explanation at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406835/oracle-sql-plus-how-to-end-command-in-sql-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, and let us know, please.

```
su -p oracle -c "$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -l mydb/mypass@localhost:1521/xe << !
    create sequence SEQ_NAME start with 1000 maxvalue 9999
    /
    create or replace trigger TRG_NAME
    before insert on TABLE_NAME
    for each row
    begin
        select SEQ_NAME.nextval into :new.MY_ID from dual;
    end;
    /
!
"
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, nearly correct! You missed `;` after `end`. Otherwise, I got `Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.`. What is the purpose of `/`?

Comment: Just corrected adding semicolon after 'end' word in the trigger definition.

Comment: @trdngy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079949/when-do-i-need-to-use-a-semicolon-vs-a-slash-in-oracle-sql/10207695#10207695

Comment: In SQL*Plus, the slash symbol forces the EXECUTION of a statement (example: create statement) or a pl/sql block (example: the create block for the trigger).

Comment: Please read the following very interesting explanation of the difference between semicolon and slash: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10207695/297267