# Does BizTalk support sub-queries?

Tags: sql, oracle, biztalk, biztalk-2010

The below query works in Oracle but not in BizTalk. A quick google has informed me that

> "Multiple statements do not work with Oracle (and other databases
>   might prevent this as well). Oracle prevents what is called SQL
>   injection, a mechanism that a hacker would use to get the database to
>   run code within the database."

Is this the same as sub-queries? Would it be possible to write this query without a sub-query?

```
update order_header oh set uploaded = 'Y'
where oh.user_def_chk_3 = 'N' 
and oh.status in('Complete','Shipped') 
and oh.client_id in (select c.client_id from client c 
    where upper(c.notes) like 'BERGEN%');
```

Comment: No idea about biztalk, but subqueries and multiple statements are different things, so this ought to be fine as a single statement. But... do you leave the trailing `;` on when you run it via the adapter? JDBC doesn't like that, and it could be that it is being interpreted by biztalk as an attempt to join two statements together - so I'd guess it isn't needed. Otherwise, actual error messages would be helpful.

Comment: @AlexPoole Wow, i didn't think that a sub query would mean multiple statements, but i never did think that using a ; would mean that BizTalk thinks there's 2 queries. removing the semi colon fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Based on feedback from wild-guess comment): BizTalk is apparently interpreting the trailing `;` as a statement separator, so it's falling foul of the multiple-statement restriction even though it's really only one. Removing the semicolon will prevent this.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10207695/266304) for background on why it is often used in SQL*Plus and SQL Developer etc. even for single statements. Things are different through other clients and adapters.

Answer (score 1):

You might place your query within a stored procedure or view.
You didn't say how you're executing the query. Are you using a WCF custom adapter?

Comment: due to the database not being administratored by us, stored procedures and views are at risk of being removed at any time. That makes those not a solution for us. We indeed use a WCF-Custom adapter.