# Error when creating supertype and subtype objects in apex script file

Tags: sql, database, object, oracle9i

I have created an object of type person and I want to create a subtype called student typ but I'm getting an error when I try to do this in a script file with the following script:

---

```
CREATE TYPE person_typ AS OBJECT(
first_name         VARCHAR2(30),
last_name          VARCHAR2(30),
dob                DATE,
telephone_Number   VARCHAR2(20),
mobile_Number      VARCHAR2(15),
address_Line1      VARCHAR2(25),
address_Line2      VARCHAR2(25),
city               VARCHAR2(30),
town               VARCHAR2(30),
postcode           VARCHAR2(8))
NOT FINAL;

CREATE TYPE student_typ UNDER person_typ(
student_Number    VARCHAR2(20),
student_Email    VARCHAR2(30))
;
```

There error displayed is :

```
Error at line 13: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" 0.03 seconds
```

Comment: You're probably missing a / after your first statement.

Comment: I'm new to Oracle and objects whats the / for?

Comment: It executes whatever is currently in the "buffer", see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079949/sql-the-semicolon-or-the-slash

Comment: Thanks again for that. I'm creating a set of objects for a piece of coursework from university. I have a person supertype the subtypes staff and student. Both of these have subtypes. I'm trying to get accustomed to how these objects are held in tables. For instance if I have a module object do I put it into a table that holds module types in order to be able to link modules to a student by putting the module ref type into a table also containing student types? If you know of any tutorials that would be helpful I'd be very grateful.