# SQL Error: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Tags: sql, ora-00904

I am an SQL rookie and I would very much appreciate some assistance on this rather basic issue.

```
alter table OCEAN_ANTENNE_TEMP
add column ANT_TILT_M number(5) not null,
ANT_FSC_ANT number(4,1) default 0;
/
```

why is this query giving me this error:

> SQL Error: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
>       00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: see the updated answer..not null should be used with default..else an exception is thrown when alter is excecuted!

Comment: You don't need the `;` **and** the `/` See here for details: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1079949/330315

Answer (score 2):

correct method is

```
alter table OCEAN_ANTENNE_TEMP 
add ( ANT_TILT_M number(5) not null, 
ANT_FSC_ANT number(4,1) default 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
alter table OCEAN_ANTENNE_TEMP 
add (ANT_TILT_M number(5) default 0 not null, 
      ANT_FSC_ANT number(4,1) default 0 not null);
```

### [See here for correct syntax](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/alter_table.php)

### [See here for Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/alter-table.html)

Comment: it still gives me an error:

Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01758: table must be empty to add mandatory (NOT NULL) column
01758. 00000 -  "table must be empty to add mandatory (NOT NULL) column"

Comment: @user3383166 The error message is pretty self-explanatory - you cannot add a NOT NULL column to a non-empty table (think about it - how is Oracle supposed to fill this column?). You should add the column without NOT NULL, fill it, and create the NOT NULL constraint afterwards.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN statement. However, a column with a NOT NULL constraint can be added to an existing table if you give a default value; otherwise, an exception is thrown when the ALTER TABLE statement is executed.`

Comment: The second link is for MySQL. It's ***not*** for Oracle.