# Sqlplus printing the result twice and with an empty line

Tags: oracle, shell, echo, sqlplus

I write shell script and want to use sqlplus, when I write:

```
#!/bin/bash
result=$(sqlplus -s user/pass@DB  << EOF
set trimspool on;
set linesize 32000;
SET SPACE 0;
SELECT MAX(DNNCMNT_ANSWER_TIME)  FROM TKIMEI.DNNCMNT_IMEI_APPRV;
/
exit;
EOF)
echo "$result"
```

the result is in txt file (I'm executing it as `ksh sql.sh > result.txt`):

```
MAX(DNNCM
---------
10-MAR-14

MAX(DNNCM
---------
10-MAR-14
```

it is automatically putting an empty line at the beginning of file and writing the result twice.

How can I fix it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079949/sql-the-semicolon-or-the-slash/10207695#10207695

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the slash.  It's causing the previous command (the select) to be repeated:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch13.htm#1006932

Also, talk to your DBA about setting up external OS authentication so you don't have to hardcode the password in a shell script for security reasons.  Once set up, you can replace the login/password combo with just a slash:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/network.1111/e16543/authentication.htm#i1007520