# Spool file is getting duplicates

Tags: sqlplus, spool

I have created the following Script ( name.sql ) which is then called from a windows.bat file.

The problem is that the .xls file that is created has twice the resultset from the SQL query.

I send you the script to help me udnerstnad what i do wrong in the .sql script:

```
set linesize 999 verify off feedback off
set markup html on entmap on spool on preformat off table 'align=right width=40% 
border=10 bordercolor=black bgcolor=white'
set echo off pagesize 1000 linesize 255 feedback off heading on;
set serveroutput off

del "D:\weekly_orders.xls"

SPOOL d:\weekly_orders1.xls

select * from x where id='1-6A86P9C'  order by x_date;

/

SPOOL OFF;

exit
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the slash that is on the line by itself.  It tells SQL/Plus to repeat the last command.

See the answers in this question regarding slash vs semi-colon when used in SQL scripts:
[When do I need to use a semicolon vs a slash in Oracle SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079949/sql-the-semicolon-or-the-slash) for more information and explanations of what is going on.