# SQLPLUS Command Skipped: set serveroutput on;

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

In ORACLE SQL Developer, this gets execute when am trying to run procedure call with its output.

```
create or replace
procedure allparam_proc(name varchar2,nestedtable_param VARCHAR2_TT)
is
begin
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('allparam_proc');
    FOR i IN nestedtable_param.FIRST..nestedtable_param.LAST LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(nestedtable_param(i));
    END LOOP;
end;
```

**Problem :**

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
fruits VARCHAR2_TT := VARCHAR2_TT('Orange','Kumquat','Grape','Banana');
begin
    allparam_proc('leo',fruits);
end;
```

**Output :**

line 1: SQLPLUS Command Skipped: set serveroutput on;

Comment: Can you mention the version of `SQL Developer` you use ? Enabling serveroutput  can be done via `View -> Dbms Output`; Semicolon is fine. Select what ever requires to be executed, and `F5` would be enough. Good Practice, is to end every `PL/SQL` block with a `/` though sometimes, the tool do it implicitly sometimes.

Comment: yes it works make it as answer.

Comment: Great, posted answer with few extra information and references. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Developer, Enabling [serveroutput](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b31695/intro.htm#CHDHJEGF) can be done via `View -> Dbms Output`

Using Semicolon is fine. But, Select what ever requires to be executed, and `F5` (Execute as a *Script*) would be enough.

Good Practice, is to end every PL/SQL block with a `/` though the tool do it implicitly sometimes. Atleast it improves readability and continuity when the `IDE` has multiple [anonymous PL/SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/overview.htm#i4603) blocks.
 [Answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079949/sql-the-semicolon-or-the-slash) have great explanations in detail.

[image]