# SQLPlus is trying to drop package twice

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, sql-drop

While executing scripts in SQLPlus I've encountered a problem:

script.sql contains the following lines

```
@some_pkg.pks
@some_pkg.pkb

drop package some_pkg;
/
```

After calling

**> sqlplus  user/password@dbname  @script.sql**

the following messages are in console:

```
Package created.
Package body created.
Package dropped.

drop package some_pkg;
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04043: object SOME_PKG does not exist
```

Please, explain what's happening here. Looks like the package is being dropped twice. Is it possible to avoid the error?

Comment: What is the content of some_pkg.pks and some_pkg.pkb?

Comment: That's because `/` runs the last statement again. Short answer: don't use `/` after a `drop`  statement See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10207695/330315

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The rules of SQLplus command execution basically are:

- Execute the current text when you encounter a semi-colon. Thus if a line doesn't end with a semi-colon, the current text continues to be collected.
- If you encounter `DECLARE` or `BEGIN`, collect all the text and do not execute on semi-colons
- If you encounter a slash (`/`), execute the collected text.

So what happens in your cases is, that both the semi-colon and the slash execute the `DROP` statements.

To fix it, remove the slash.

You only need the slash if you have a block of PL/SQL, which always with an `END` statement. Use semicolons for everything else.

Note: the above rules are simplified. It's more complex in practice.

Comment: Or remove the semi-colon... the slash on its own will still then execute the drop command in the buffer. (But be consistent in how you do this in your code.)

Comment: Yes, I agree. But as a simple rule for writing consistent code and helping your eyes spot mistakes, I recommend the use the slash for PL/SQL blocks only and semi-colons otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Some examples will help to understand rules:

1. Below code will be executed once

```
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('executed');
end;
/
```

2. Below code will not execute (missing semicolon)

```
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('executed')
end
/
```

3. Below code will be executed twice

```
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('executed');
end;
/
/
```

4. Below code will be executed once

```
select 1 from dual
/
```

5. Below code will be executed once

```
select 1 from dual;
```

6. Below code will be executed twice

```
select 1 from dual;
/
```