# Can comments be started in the first line before a query in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, snaplogic

As in I just want to execute a query with a comment.

Example:

```
/*Selects all columns and rows*/
SELECT * FROM "SNAPLOGIC"."CUSTCOMM1"
```

or

```
-- comment
select * from "SNAPLOGIC"."CUSTCOMM1"
```

Can we execute in Oracle SQL?

Note: These statements can be executed in tools like DBeaver.

Comment: Madhu, was the `or` supposed to be included in the code or not?

Comment: Do you have a reason to think you can't have a comment immediately before a statement? Have you experienced a problem in a specific client (and version)? (I wonder if you're seeing a variaion [of this behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43113278/266304) maybe?)

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: I got this error message if i execute in an application--
SQL operation failed, Reason: invalid batch command: invalid SELECT batch command 0, error code: 17080

Comment: "in an application" -  which application, and how are you executing it? The comment isn't part of the statement, and it sounds like whatever you're using isn't expecting to see it. Context is everything though...

Answer (score 0):

The first line is a comment above your query.

If there is an error message displaying, the lack of spaces could be the cause.

```
/* Selects all columns and rows */
SELECT * FROM "SNAPLOGIC"."CUSTCOMM1"
```

Comment: Iam getting this error message when executed:--
SQL operation failed, Reason: invalid batch command: invalid SELECT batch command 0, error code: 17080