# ORA-04071: missing BEFORE, AFTER or INSTEAD OF keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am writing some PL/SQL code for a apex database application. With the code a want to realise that when I make a purchase order, a purchase orderline is automatically generated based on the purchase order_id. However, I'm getting a `ORA-04071` error running the code below:

```
create or replace trigger "INKOOPORDER_T1"/
AFTER insert or update or delete on INKOOPORDER
for each row begin

INSERT INTO INKOOPORDERREGEL
    (I_nummer)
SELECT
    I_nummer
    FROM inkooporderregel
go
end/
```

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: You are missing `;` at the end of the insert. And there is no `GO` in SQL. And the `/` after the first line is incorrect as well. See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10207695/330315

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ur query has some syntax errors

try below code

I removed `/` from first line and after `End`, put `;` at the end of insert statement and deleted `go`.Also after `end` a `;`

```
create or replace trigger "INKOOPORDER_T1"
AFTER insert or update or delete on INKOOPORDER
for each row 
begin

INSERT INTO INKOOPORDERREGEL
    (I_nummer)
SELECT
    I_nummer
    FROM inkooporderregel;

end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, the error is gone indeed. However A new purchase order is not shown in purchase order line. Do I need to add somthing to the code?

Comment: @BoudewijnVisser u r inserting I_Number to INKOOPORDERREGEL by selecting I_Number from same table..i can't understand what u r achieving here

Comment: @BoudewijnVisser r u trying to insert the value from INKOOPORDER to INKOOPORDERREGEL