# How to make a sql function and test it at the same sheet?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to make an sql function (or procedure) in sql developer and test in at the same sheet. I've got some error message. 
This is my code:

```
CREATE or replace function myProc (trace_items_ids IN arrayofnumbers)
RETURN tableof2numbers
is 
tr          tableof2numbers := tableof2numbers();

BEGIN
select object_id, parent_id
bulk collect into tr
from objects;
return tr;
END;

select * from TABLE(myProc(arrayofnumbers(1,2)))
```

and I've got an error :

> ORA-00955. 00000 -  "name is already used by an existing object"
>        Cause:
>        Action:

How can I test my function?

Comment: Apparently there is already some object (but not a function) in the database with that name. `select object_name, object_type from user_objects where object_name = 'MYPROC'`  will show you what it is.

Comment: No, I've created function MYPROC2 and it have the same error.

Comment: So what does the `select` return?

Comment: It returns my function. Now I have a compilation error : PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT"

Comment: You need to terminate the `create procedure` with a `/`: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10207695/330315

Comment: I had some errors in my pl/sql function. Now I have no problems, thank you.

Comment: It works, when first I write function declaration and then I do a query select. I use 2 sheets and perform it separately.