# Mixing DDL and DML statements in a single script

Tags: oracle

I'm writing a script that will add an ID column to a table, including all the sequences and triggers to keep it automatically up to date. It will perform the following:

- Add a column to a table
- Create a sequence
- Create a trigger
- **Update existing rows to use sequence values**
- Set the field to not nullable

The problem I have is with the line in bold - it would be an `UPDATE` statement in a DDL script. The error I get is:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "UPDATE"

I've tried wrapping the `UPDATE` in a `BEGIN` and `END` block, with no success.

Is it possible to include an `UPDATE` statement in a DDL script?

Here's what I have so far:

```
ALTER TABLE RETAILER ADD (RETAILER_ID NUMBER );

CREATE SEQUENCE RETAILER_ID_SEQ;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER RETAILER_ADD_TRG
BEFORE INSERT ON RETAILER
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT RETAILER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO :new.RETAILER_ID FROM dual;
END;

-- Doesn't like this part...
UPDATE RETAILER SET RETAILER_ID = RETAILER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
COMMIT;

ALTER TABLE RETAILER MODIFY (RETAILER_ID NOT NULL);
```

Comment: You need a `/` after the `create trigger` statement: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10207695/330315

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name, can you write this as an answer so I can accept it? Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

An efficient way of setting that value would be:

```
UPDATE RETAILER SET RETAILER_ID = ROWNUM;
```

... and then creating the sequence, reading the number of rows in RETAILER to set the START WITH value (a bit of trivial PL/SQL and dynamic SQL).

12c supports:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE RETAILER_ID_SEQ;
ALTER TABLE RETAILER ADD (RETAILER_ID NUMBER DEFAULT RETAILER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL NOT NULL );
```

... by the way, so no need for defining your own trigger.

http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_3001.htm

> The DEFAULT expression can include the sequence pseudocolumns CURRVAL and NEXTVAL, as long as the sequence exists and you have the privileges necessary to access it. Users who perform subsequent inserts that use the DEFAULT expression must have the INSERT privilege on the table and the SELECT privilege on the sequence. If the sequence is later dropped, then subsequent insert statements where the DEFAULT expression is used will result in an error. If you are adding a new column to a table, then the order in which NEXTVAL is assigned to each existing row is nondeterministic

Comment: Did you mean `rownum` rather than `rowid`?  I don't see how a `rowid` would fit in an integer `retailer_id` column...

Comment: Hah -- yes of course. Only been awake 5 minutes. Cheers.

Comment: In any case, the real issue is the missing `/` as  @a_horse_with_no_name mentioned. Then both solutions work, but using `RETAILER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL` instead of `ROWNUM` has the advantage that the sequence is already up-to-date after the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: "Only been awake 5 minutes" .  The first SO answer of the day is always the most enjoyable one ;-)

Comment: Some good advice in here, but the problem was to do with mixing DDL and DML statements, which can be resolved by adding a slash after statements that are followed by a change in concerns.