# Running SQL from Batch File

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have a batch file which is running this sql script.

```
set pagesize 200
spool d:\Patron\Airport_Monitoring.txt
select  count (*) from (
select x.ext_plaza_id from st_ledger p, pa_lane_txn x where P.EVENT_ID in  (400,444) and p.posted_date > sysdate - 1/24 
and X.TXN_ID = P.PA_LANE_TXN_ID ) plz_list 
where plz_list.ext_plaza_id like '2002%';           
/
spool off 
exit;
```

The output count is being repeated twice on the output text file. Is there a way, I can have the count only written once on the output file.

```
COUNT(*)                                                                      
----------                                                                      
        31                                                                      

COUNT(*)                                                                      
----------                                                                      
       31
```

Thanks

Comment: Get rid of that slash.

Comment: And here is an explanation why you need to get rid of that `/`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10207695/330315