# Oracle database, SQL Query output

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm getting a really annoying bug. If I run a script with an a simple query as this:

```
SELECT C.cnum
FROM CLASS C
WHERE C.room = '115'
```

I get this output on the terminal and the cursor keeps blinking. I get the same result for several different queries.

```
SQL> @test.sql
  4
```

Comment: What client software are you using?

Comment: SQL statements need to be terminated using a `;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting a `/` on a new line.

Comment: Now i get the desired output. Why does this happen?

Comment: Glad to help :) End of file does not finish the script automatically as would be expected.

Comment: @AymenRizwan: a `;` would be a better choice: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10207695/330315

Comment: `/` is for executing embedded statements like PL/SQL not for a SQL
 statement. You should in fact use semi-colon. Also, using `/` in SQL statements, there is a chance that you might end up executing the query again which is in the buffer. so, semi-colon is a better choice in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT C.cnum
FROM CLASS C
WHERE C.room = '115'
```

You must **terminate** the SQL statement with **semi-colon**.

```
SELECT C.cnum
FROM CLASS C
WHERE C.room = '115';
```

Also, prefer using `/` for **PL/SQL** objects where you have lot of statements embedded. If you use `/` for **SQL statements**, chances are that you might end up executing the statement twice as the previous executed statement is in the current buffer, and `/` executes statements in the current buffer.