# How to call a sql function?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle12c

I have written a function minimum2 which take two numbers as arguments and returns the minimum number. This function compiles without any error. when I call the function `minimum(1,2);` I get the errors PLS-00103. Here is the function and the function call:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION minimum2(v1 number, v2 number) RETURN number IS
     BEGIN
       IF v1 < v2 THEN
         RETURN v1;
       ELSE
         RETURN v2;
       END IF;
     END;     
 --I call the function asl follow
 minimum2(1,2);
```

What did I do wrong? I wrote this code in sql developer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run a `select`

```
select minimum2(1,2) 
from dual
```

You also need to end the function with a `/`:

[image]

For details on how and why to use the `/` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079949/when-do-i-need-to-use-a-semicolon-vs-a-slash-in-oracle-sql/10207695#10207695)

---

Are you aware that there is a built-in function for that?

```
select least(1,2) 
from dual
```

Comment: I tried select but got the same errors. I dont want use the built-in function i want to know why my function call does not work :)

Comment: @Max_Salah: and what error **exactly** did you get with the `select`? You _did_ end the `create function` with a `/` did you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079949/when-do-i-need-to-use-a-semicolon-vs-a-slash-in-oracle-sql/10207695#10207695

Answer (score 1):

--specifying 'in' and 'out' to parameters is important or it can work as it is, but best practice is to use:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION minimum2(v1 IN number, v2 IN number) RETURN number IS
     BEGIN
       IF v1 < v2 THEN
         RETURN v1;
       ELSE
         RETURN v2;
       END IF;
     END;
```

--I call the function as follows through anonymous block and you can not call the function directly.

```
set serveroutput on;
begin
dbms_output.put_line('Output is ' || minimum2(1,2));
END;
/
```

Comment: when i run the code inclusive the function call i get the error ERROR(12,1): PLS-00103: founded the Symbol "SET"

Comment: Those are two separate statements (one SQL*Plus, one PL/SQL). You need to run them one at a time.