# Why can't I write DDL directly after a PLSQL anonymous block?

Tags: oracle, plsql, ddl, sql-scripts

I have the following simple script.

```
declare
begin
  null;
end;

create table &&DB_SCHEMA..test_table (
   test_column varchar(20)
);
```

Executing it ends with the following error

> ORA-06550: line 6, column 1:
>
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE"
>
> 6550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>
> *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>
> *Action:

Can't I use the DDL directly after an anonymous block? Am I forced to do it with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` inside the anonymous block?

Comment: Why DDL specifically? You can't do _anything_ without terminating the block.

Comment: Quite a rookie when it comes to PL/SQL therefore I did not know about this magical slash.

Comment: The slash isn't really part of PL/SQL - it'll depend on the client app. The point is that `select` wouldn't have worked either, or `insert`, `update`, `delete` etc.

Comment: I agree, it is just that I have had this problem on this specific DDL, I do not oppose to the fact that it does not work with DML either. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are simply missing a '/':

```
SQL> declare
  2  begin
  3    null;
  4  end;
  5  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> create table create_test_table (
  2     test_column varchar(20)
  3  );

Table created.
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079949/when-do-i-need-to-use-a-semicolon-vs-a-slash-in-oracle-sql) you find something more.

Comment: That was it! Thank you!