# Why am I encountering the symbol end of file in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a trigger for auto incrementing id value in Oracle. Here is the code that I've tried to use

```
create or replace 
trigger themes_on_insert
before insert on THEME
for each row
begin
select themes_sequence.nextval
into :new.ID
from dummy
end;
```

> Error(5,4): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with          << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statements must be ended with a `;` and the whole PL/SQL block must be ended with a `/`

```
create or replace trigger themes_on_insert
  before insert on THEME
  for each row
begin
  select themes_sequence.nextval
  into :new.ID
  from dummy; --<< missing ; here
end;
/
```

The `select` is actually not necessary, this can be simplified to:

```
create or replace trigger themes_on_insert
  before insert on THEME
  for each row
begin
  :new.ID := themes_sequence.nextval;
end;
/
```

For details on why the `/` is needed see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10207695/330315)

Answer (score 0):

; missing after from dummy?

```
create or replace 
trigger themes_on_insert
before insert on THEME
for each row
begin
select themes_sequence.nextval
into :new.ID
from dummy;
end;
```