# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, compiler-errors

This PL/SQL statement:

```
FUNCTION f_comparestring(ps_string1 VARCHAR2, ps_string2 VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
          ps_match VARCHAR2(5);
        BEGIN
          IF (ps_string1 = ps_strin2) THEN
            ps_match := 'TRUE';
          ELSE
            ps_match := 'FALSE';
          END IF;
          RETURN ps_match;
        END;
```

Raises the following error:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: begin end function pragma procedure

I am pretty much at a loss. This appears to be a rather simple statement. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `ps_string2` not `ps_strin2`  in the `IF`. To create a function you need to use `create function`

You also need a `/` after the PL/SQL block. 
For details see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10207695/330315

So the correct statement is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_comparestring(ps_string1 VARCHAR2, ps_string2 VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  ps_match VARCHAR2(5);
BEGIN
  IF (ps_string1 = ps_string2) THEN
    ps_match := 'TRUE';
  ELSE
    ps_match := 'FALSE';
  END IF;
  RETURN ps_match;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, but is it necessary to add a `CREATE` in front of `FUNCTION` when created inside a Package Body?

Comment: @Noah: no, inside a package it's not necessary. But if you are creating a package you need to show us the whole statement for the package body.