# What does "Encountered the symbol "Update" means?"

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

When I try try implement the trigger statement, I got the error message "Encountered the symbol "Update"" but I don't what why it happened

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Trigger1
before DELETE OR UPDATE OR INSERT ON condition
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (SYSDATE NOT BETWEEN
to_date(to_char(SYSDATE, 'DD.MM.RRRR') || '06:00', 'DD.MM.RRRR HH24:MI' )
AND to_date(to_char(SYSDATE, 'DD.MM.RRRR') || '12:00', 'DD.MM.RRRR-HH24:MI')) BEGIN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20001,
'You can only change my data between 06:00 and 12:00 ! ');
END;

update condition
set name='abc', description='xyz'
where condition_id=1;
```

Comment: I added the oracle tag, which is a guess based on your use of RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR. If this is not correct, please fix the tags. Always tag your questions appropriately. This will get you better answers, because people who know a subject will follow the tags, and your question is more likely to be found by the right people if you tag it well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079949/when-do-i-need-to-use-a-semicolon-vs-a-slash-in-oracle-sql/10207695#10207695

Comment: thanks for adding the tag, I am learaning pl/sql from Oracle but I forgot to include it

Comment: As a general rule, never omit the error prefix (ORA-... or whatever) when posting questions.

Comment: `to_date(to_char(sysdate, 'DD.MM.RRRR') || '06:00', 'DD.MM.RRRR HH24:MI')` can be written as `trunc(sysdate) + 6/24`.

Comment: Shouldn't we add the SQLPLUS tag here ? I don't think other clients have the same requirements

Answer (score 2):

PL/SQL code needs to be terminated by a `/` character within most Oracle development environments (e.g. SQL*Plus or SQL Developer).  Since you didn't terminate your `CREATE TRIGGER` statement, it's interpreting the next `update condition ...` statement as part of the PL\SQL code when you are executing it, but since it's been placed after the closing `END;` statement it's invalid.

Adding a `/` after the closing `END;` should clear things up for you.

Comment: Isn't that a specific requirement for SQLPLUS ? When using other clients they seem less finicky

Answer (score 1):

Put `/` at the next line after the trigger decleration

Comment: Thanks for your help, I forgot to put it at the end