# Duplication of data on oracle sql report

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I am printing tablespace names in oracle but am facing duplicate data issue on the sqlplus console. Please share your thoughts if you know how to avoid this issue.

```
set heading on
set echo off
set feedback off trimspool on verify off
set lines 120
set pages 2000
prompt DATE
select sysdate from dual;
/
prompt
prompt
prompt =====================================
prompt            Tablespaces
prompt =====================================
break on report
select name from v$tablespace ;
/

clear break
clear compute
```

[image: TableSpace_List]

Comment: See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079949/when-do-i-need-to-use-a-semicolon-vs-a-slash-in-oracle-sql

Answer (score 1):

And as the docs say about "slash": https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve004.htm

> Executes the most recently executed SQL command or PL/SQL block which
>   is stored in the SQL buffer.

So `select name from v$tablespace ;`is executed twice in your case