# Oracle SQL error if trying to create comparison

Tags: sql, oracle

If I try to run:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_COMPARISON.CREATE_COMPARISON(
    comparison_name => 'compare_docdestruct',
    schema_name     => 'DOCDES',
    object_name     => 'KVT_DOCDESTRUCT',    
    remote_schema_name => 'DOCDES2',    
    remote_object_name => 'KVT_DOCDESTRUCT');
END;
```

I get the following error:

```
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CREATE_COMPARISON'
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
```

I do not understand what the problem is. Can you help?

Comment: Isn't `dblink_name` a mandatory parameter?

Comment: you typically need a `/` after a PL/SQL block: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1079949/330315

Comment: The error seems pretty self-explanatory. It says you are not passing the right number of parameters, or the wrong number of parameters. [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/DBMS_COMPARISON.html#GUID-04ABD84A-9526-462D-A30B-F086CB6EAF60) lists them.