# How to use a PL/SQL procedure file with SQL*Plus

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I want to execute a PL/SQL procedure which is inside a .sql file.

I'm calling my .sql file with SQL*Plus like this :

```
@myfile.sql
```

And here is myfile.sql

```
declare 
    listTotal number := 0;
    nbrCommit number := 200;
begin
    select count(1) into listTotal from MKTMLF.TMP_ID_CLI_SUPPR;
    [... different updates here ....]
commit;
    if listTotal > nbrCommit THEN
        [... different updates here ....]
        commit;
    end if;
end;
```

When i paste that PL/SQL inside Oracle SQL developer it's OK, it tells me "Procedure PL/SQL finished" but when i do it with SQL*Plus it just show me a number

```
55
```

and nothing else! Actually i have found that these number is the number of lines inside my file.sql.

What is the problem? Why is it OK inside Oracle SQL developer and with SQL*Plus?

Comment: Type a forward slash '/' and your procedure will run. You have put your code in the buffer but you need to tell it to run what's in the buffer - hence the '/'.

Comment: @BriteSponge Tahnk you so much!!! That "/" make it works!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1079949/330315

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add a forward slash `/` at the end of file. That will ask the client to run the code.

The trailing / is something that sqlplus and sqlcl look for to know it's the end of the block and please run the above code block.

In SQLDEV, there is a smart parser that can determine the end of the block syntactically to know what to execute.