# How to execute a procedure in oracle developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to execute the procedure that I created, however whenever I do EXEC ProductLineSale; it tells me Error(456,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXEC"

```
ALTER TABLE Product

ADD SalePrice DECIMAL(6,2); 

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ProductLineSale 

AS 

BEGIN 

UPDATE Product
SET SalePrice = 0.90 * ProductStandardPrice
WHERE ProductStandardPrice >= 400;

 UPDATE Product
SET SalePrice = 0.85 * ProductStandardPrice
WHERE ProductStandardPrice < 400;

END;

EXEC ProductLineSale;

select *
FROM Product;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `/` before `EXEC`  to close `PROCEDURE`

See [why we need forward slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079949/when-do-i-need-to-use-a-semicolon-vs-a-slash-in-oracle-sql):

> For other PL/SQL blocks, including Procedures, Functions, Packages and Triggers, because they are multiple line programs, Oracle need a way to know when to run the block, so we have to write a forward slash at the end of each block to let Oracle run it.

Comment: I tried this, but I still am getting the same error.

Comment: @alphaX Add `/` before

Comment: Add the `/` before what?

Comment: @alphaX before execute, so previous statement is closed

Comment: `EXECUTE` is a SQL*Plus command. `EXEC` is an accepted abbreviation of exactly the same thing.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Thank you, I updated my answer to reflect valid solution, please consider undo down vote

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a '/' - this tells SQL Developer that your stored procedure declaration is finished and you're ready to compile it.

Add a '/' after the END; and before the EXECUTE.

```
--create table product (id integer,
--                      productstandardprice number(7,2));
--                      
--insert into product values (1, 19.95, 0);
--insert into product values (2, 7995.99);
alter table PRODUCT add SALEPRICE decimal(6, 2);

create or replace procedure PRODUCTLINESALE as
begin
  update PRODUCT
     set
    SALEPRICE = 0.90 * PRODUCTSTANDARDPRICE
   where PRODUCTSTANDARDPRICE >= 400;

  update PRODUCT
     set
    SALEPRICE = 0.85 * PRODUCTSTANDARDPRICE
   where PRODUCTSTANDARDPRICE < 400;

end;
/

exec PRODUCTLINESALE;

select *
  from PRODUCT;
```

I selected the create and everything after with my cursor, and then hit F5

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose it with `Begin` and `End`

```
ALTER TABLE Product

ADD SalePrice DECIMAL(6,2); 

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ProductLineSale 

AS 

BEGIN 

UPDATE Product
SET SalePrice = 0.90 * ProductStandardPrice
WHERE ProductStandardPrice >= 400;

 UPDATE Product
SET SalePrice = 0.85 * ProductStandardPrice
WHERE ProductStandardPrice < 400;

END;

BEGIN
EXECUTE ProductLineSale;
END;

select *
FROM Product
```

Comment: I did this, but then I get the same error number but this time with the word Begin.

Comment: what is the name of your package ?

Comment: What do you mean the name of my package?

Answer (score 0):

On a different note, you may have a single update statement which would be more efficient than two statements.

```
UPDATE product
SET saleprice =
          CASE
               WHEN productstandardprice >= 400 THEN 0.90 * productstandardprice
               WHEN productstandardprice < 400  THEN 0.85 * productstandardprice
          END;
```

Furthermore, It is advisable not to have another column in the table if it can be generated easily from existing columns. You should prefer [**VIRTUAL COLUMNS**](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1)

So, you may redefine the `saleprice` column

```
ALTER TABLE product ADD (
      SalePrice    DECIMAL(6,2)  GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
               CASE
                    WHEN productstandardprice >= 400 THEN 0.90 * productstandardprice
                    WHEN productstandardprice < 400  THEN 0.85 * productstandardprice
               END
          )
);
```

Now, the column will automatically display the computed value when you run a select from the table