# Oracle to_char format mask covering 0.1 -> .1 case

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have the following situation:

```
create table test1(c1 number, c2 varchar2(250 char));
/
insert into test1 values(0.11, 0.11);
/
select * from test1;
```

will give me:

```
C1       C2
0.11    .11
```

I want to store a number like 0.11 as it is, without removing the 0. Problem is that in that varchar2 column I can also store values like "1.123", "0.123456789", "test123". So basically it can be a number with any precision or even a string. 
I think my only chance is to use the "fmt" parameter of to_char, but I can't find a mask that could solve any given number of digits and strings

Comment: If you're storing a string, use a string literal - i.e. `insert into test1 values (0.11, '0.11');`

Answer (score 0):

You can try below using to_char() and fmt as '90D90'

```
create table test1(c1 number, c2 varchar2(250 char))END;
```

/

```
insert into test1 values(0.11, to_char(0.11, '90D90'))END;
```

/

```
select * from test1;
```

Comment: Please do not use `;` **and** `/` to separate statements (`/` will run the `create table` twice!, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079949/when-do-i-need-to-use-a-semicolon-vs-a-slash-in-oracle-sql/10207695#10207695) for details)

Comment: I need a solution that will work with any general situation. "SELECT to_char(0.11111, '90D90') FROM DUAL" will not work as expected for example. Even worse the value could be a string also: "SELECT to_char('test123', '90D90') FROM DUAL" will throw an error

Comment: @LucaIulian, what do u mean by general situation - could you please explain a bit more

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution using regex:

```
select regexp_replace('.11115', '^(\.\d+)$', '0\1') from dual
```

This searches if it starts with a dot and continues only with digits. Won't crash if you pass it a string and the precision length doesn't matter