# Oracle command works in database but not in SQLPlus

Tags: oracle, batch-file, sqlplus

I'm currently trying to implement a bash script that runs at the end of the day that runs a simple oracle query. The command works just fine in Oracle but when inside a .sql file it does not run.

I've attempted to put all of the code on one line and adding semicolons.

---

Contents of batch file (with user/pass altered):

```
sqlplus username/password@database @set_changed.sql
```

---

Contents of set_changed.sql file:

```
UPDATE ris_web a
SET a.changed = 0
where exists
(
    select modified_date from invn_sbs b
    where b.item_sid = a.item_sid
        and b.modified_date <= sysdate-1
);
COMMIT;
END;
```

---

Comment: Do you get the same error message when you use EXIT; instead of END; ?

Comment: What's the purpose of the pipe `|` in your batch file? You are passing the output of the `exit` command, so nothing, to the input of `sqlplus`; is that really what you want?

Comment: @nebulopathy After replacing `END;` with `EXIT;` I'm just seeing the cursor blink after it says "Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production"

Comment: @aschipfl It wasn't anything important. I took it out. It was just something I was experimenting with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original syntax was correct. There were uncommitted changes in sqldeveloper that were causing the .sql file to never finish running. Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLPlus you should use a `/` on a separate line to terminate an SQL statement or PL/SQL block instead of using a semicolon, so change your file to

```
UPDATE ris_web a
SET a.changed = 0
where exists
(
    select modified_date from invn_sbs b
    where b.item_sid = a.item_sid
        and b.modified_date <= sysdate-1
)
/

SHOW ERRORS
/

COMMIT
/

SHOW ERRORS
/

END
```

[You might also want to have a look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079949/when-do-i-need-to-use-a-semicolon-vs-a-slash-in-oracle-sql)

Comment: Hi @bobjarvis. Thank you for your response. When I altered my set_changed.sql file to match your response it just hangs on the command line. I've attempted to experiment with your solution in an attempt to get it working but I'm still not able to find any success.

Answer (score 0):

You have `end;` command at the end of the script but no `BEGIN` for it.

Simply replace the `END;` with `/`

Comment: Hi @Tejash----ORA-00980. Thank you for your response. I've tried replacing the `END;` with `/` and also adding a `BEGIN` and I still haven't managed to get it working.

Comment: No, you don't have to add `BEGIN`. Just replace `END` with `/`

Comment: Right. I replaced `END` with `/` on my original query and it still did not work.