# Oracle: Statements running into each other

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-trigger

I am not fluent with Oracle, and am testing out an auto-incrementing trigger required for older versions, where `IDENTITY` is not yet available.

```
CREATE TABLE stuff (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    data varchar(255)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE stuff_sequence;
CREATE TRIGGER test
BEFORE INSERT ON stuff
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT stuff_sequence.nextval INTO :new.id FROM dual;
END;

INSERT INTO stuff(data) VALUES('test');
```

Using SQL Developer, I can run the `CREATE TABLE` statement, and then the `CREATE SEQUENCE` statement, but when I run the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement, it highlights the `INSERT` statement as well, and then complains about `Encountered the symbol "INSERT". Obviously, if I try to run the whole lot as a single script I get the same error.

What is happening here, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put `/` at the end of the trigger code. Which represents the end of the code above it.

```
CREATE TRIGGER test
BEFORE INSERT ON stuff
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT stuff_sequence.nextval INTO :new.id FROM dual;
END;
/ -- this

INSERT INTO stuff(data) VALUES('test');
```

`/` during the entering of a DML or DDL or PL/SQL means "terminate the current statement, execute it and store it to the SQLPLUS buffer" and `/` is needed in multiple lines code to indicate that the code is ending here.

Comment: Sorry, what is the slash and why do I use it? Is it like `GO` in Microsoft?

Comment: It represents the end of the code which is written above it. Each plsql code in a single script needs to be ended with `/`

Comment: If this answer solved your issue then please accept it, so that question is marked as resolved.

Comment: I did ask what was happening. I wasn’t aware that I was writing any plsql code as such, just SQL. The answer doesn’t explain why the slash goes after the `CREATE TRIGGER` and not elsewhere. To me adding the slash at this point but nowhere else looks like a magical incantation.

Comment: `/` during the entering of a DML or DDL or PL/SQL means "terminate the current statement, execute it and store it to the SQLPLUS buffer" and `/` is needed in multiple lines code to indicate that the code is ending here.

Comment: But why there and not after the other statements?

Comment: You have only one PL/SQL code here. That is why.. And it is good practice to put `/` after each statement

Comment: So, what you’re saying is that `CREATE TRIGGER` is not regarded as a normal SQL DDL statement, but rather a switch to PLSQL. Is that what you’re saying? The rest is normal SQL.

Comment: Yes, It is. I think you got it!!

Comment: OK, I’ve found the relevant documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/sqlrf/CREATE-TRIGGER.html#GUID-EE0DF3AA-7ADC-4171-B8E8-138BE9224E3B. The key is that the trigger, in this case is an anonymous PL/SQL block. The slash is _not_ required for pure DDL, but it is required for PL/SQL. I thought Microsoft was the weird one with the `GO` statement.

Comment: For more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079949/when-do-i-need-to-use-a-semicolon-vs-a-slash-in-oracle-sql#answer-11211137