# What is the reason of 'Error starting at line : 1 in command -'?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm running these commands in Oracle SQL Developer 20.4.0.379.

```
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE works_in';
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
            RAISE;
        END IF;
END;

BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE depends';
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
            RAISE;
        END IF;
END;

BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE wards';
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
            RAISE;
        END IF;
END;

BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE doctors';
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
            RAISE;
        END IF;
END;
```

Then it returns an error:

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 10, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" 
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

On the other hand, when I run each PL/SQL blocks one-by-one, there is no error. Could you please elaborate on this issue?

Comment: What happens if you enclose everything in one parent block like `BEGIN BEGIN ... END; ... BEGIN ... END; END;`?

Comment: @stickybit I'm new to SQL. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: PL/SQL blocks should be separated by forward slash (`/`) in SQL*Plus, and the same is in F5 mode of SQL Developer. For more explanation check [this thread on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079949/when-do-i-need-to-use-a-semicolon-vs-a-slash-in-oracle-sql/10207695).

Comment: I'm afraid, no, I cannot. I already outlined what I mean. What don't you understand?

Comment: Thank you so much @astentx.  Lacking `/` is the gist of my problem. I hope that you can write your comment as answer so that I can accept it.