# Why the output is printing twice while executing loop in plsql?

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper, plsql-package

```sql
set serveroutput on;
Declare
    d_name varchar(25);
    cursor dep_cur is
    select distinct department_name from department;
BEGIN 
    dbms_output.put_line('Department Names are :');
    open dep_cur;
    
    LOOP
        fetch dep_cur
            into d_name;
              
        exit when dep_cur%notfound;    
        dbms_output.put_line(d_name);  
    END LOOP;
    close dep_cur;
END;
/
```

output:

```
Department Names are :                                                          
ADMIN                                                                           
TESTING                                                                         
DEVELOPMENT                                                                     
Department Names are :                                                          
ADMIN                                                                           
TESTING                                                                         
DEVELOPMENT
```

Expected output:

```
Department Names are :     
ADMIN
DEVELOPMENT
```

Comment: Your example in the question [working as expected](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=95a1dde84b7be40eff911a3aba72e54e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have an anonymous BEGIN-END block with a semicolon and forward slash at the end. In this case the slash executes the code block once again.

Useful resources:

- Read more about what is the purpose of slash in [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve004.htm)
- Read more about when to use semicolon or slash in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1079949/2019964)

Comment: it worked after removing slash but removing semicolon and using only slash was giving an error

Comment: Ok, thanks. Updated my answer by removing that sentence :)