# Tables not showing up after adding them in command line (Oracle SQL)

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I added a test table using cmd sql

```
CREATE TABLE TESTJDBC (NAME varchar(8), NUM NUMBER);
INSERT INTO TESTJDBC VALUES ('ALIS', 67);
INSERT INTO TESTJDBC VALUES ('BOB', 345);
COMMIT;
```

The response was that it was successfully added, table created, row added, etc. But when I do

```
select NAME, NUM from TESTJDBC
```

or

```
select * from TESTJDBC
```

I just get a blank line with an indented "2"

```
SQL> select NAME, NUM from TESTJDBC
    2
```

I connected to my database on sql developer, and on there I can't even find the table. I know the table itself is definitely there, because when I try to create a new table with the same name I can't. What's the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should **terminate** the statement with semi-colon:

```
select name, num from testjdbc;
```

or forward slash:

```
select name, num from testjdbc
/
```

Because, "indented 2" just means that you're now in line #2 and should enter some more code (if you want).

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21145229/1509264) for what using a semi-colon or a slash means.