# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following , I am running the following script :

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION BOLUM_ADI(P_BOLUMNO IN NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS 
  WBOLUM_ADI VARCHAR2(30);
  BEGIN

    SELECT DEPARTMENT_NAME INTO WBOLUM_ADI FROM DEPARTMENTS 
    WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = P_BOLUMNO;
   RETURN(WBOLUM_ADI);
 END;
```

and ı got this error :

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when  expecting one of
> the following:;

please give me some helpful advice . whenever ı want to create a function ı got errors that ıncludes this expression : In a procedure, the RETURN clause cannot contain an expression

Comment: Which environment are you doing this in? SQL Developer?

Comment: Function works in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/leuMhBrh). How about slash at the end? [When do I need to use a semicolon vs a slash in Oracle SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079949/when-do-i-need-to-use-a-semicolon-vs-a-slash-in-oracle-sql)

Comment: You need to place a forward slash (`/`) at the very end to depict the end of the statement. PL/SQL accepts semicolon as part of code so SQL\*Plus doesn't recognoze the end of your script

Comment: btw ı am doing SQL developer

Comment: After the `END;` you need to put `/` on a newline as that is the SQL\*Plus and SQL Developer PL/SQL statement terminator.

Comment: also ıt doesn't work in dbfiddle